# Publish unlisted NuGet package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I want to publish a new version of a NuGet package, but I want it automatically in an **Unlisted** status. When I manually upload the `.nupkg` file to [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/), in the preview there is an option to unlist the package from search results:

---

[image: package visibility option on nuget]

---

Is there a way to do that with `nuget.exe` or `dotnet nuget`?

I was able to use **PUSH + DELETE** commands to achieve this, but I'm not sure this is the same as the above manual action.
For instance, one of the concerns is what happens to the package's RSS (`atom.xml`)?
Does it first get a new entry which is then deleted later on? In which case, is it possible that someone would still get notified about this release?

Last, I am aware of private NuGet feeds, but regardless, I would still like to use just the main NuGet, for convenience's sake.